# Using "Authy Two Factor Authentication" in custom login page

Tags: plugins

I have created a custom login page (instead of wp-login that we have in wordpress) and I want to integrate Authy there, I searched everywhere but couldn't find any answers.

I have created a custom form and used a hook `add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_login' );` and from there I am validating user credentials, something like:

```
   `$creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = $username;
    $creds['user_password'] = $_POST['login_password'];
    $creds['remember'] = true;
    $user_validate = wp_signon( $creds, false );
    if ( !is_wp_error($user_validate) ){
      header('Location: '.home_url());
         exit(); 
    }`
```

if the users credentials are valid the user is being redirected to the home page while being logged in too.
I have two questions here:

1. I tried enabling Authy for my profile from wp-admin, I tried logging in then and it asked for Authy key that I received as a text message, but I wasn't logged in, instead I was redirected to the home url without being logged in. How do I fix this?
2. How do I allow a user to enable Authy from any custom template (not through wp-login).?

I am new to wordpress, I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: You have tried `wp_signon( $creds, true)` and `$creds['user_login'] = $_POST['$username']` ?

Comment: @BindiyaPatoliya Yes.

Comment: Try `if ( is_wp_error($user) ) { echo $user->get_error_message(); }` and which error you get.

Comment: Remove your code `if ( !is_wp_error($user_validate) ){      header('Location: '.home_url());         exit();`

Comment: The problem is, the above code for login is working fine for non-authy enabled users, for authy enabled users, after entering my username and password, I am being redirected to a page where I have to enter the authy code, after entering that I am being redirected to the home page without being logged in.

Comment: You are redirecting because you have write `if ( !is_wp_error($user_validate) ){ header('Location: '.home_url()); `